# What's the difference between Spring BeanFactoryAware and ApplicationContextAware?

Tags: java, spring

Both can be used to get bean instance, but which one is better to be used to implement?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you need a reference to the `BeanFactory`, then use `BeanFactoryAware`. If you need a reference to the `ApplicationContext`, then use `ApplicationContextAware`.

Note that the `ApplicationContext` interface is a subclass of `BeanFactory`, and provides additional methods on top of the basic `BeanFactory` interface.

If all you need to do is call `getBean()`, then `BeanFactory` is sufficient.

Note also that Spring 2.5+ provides a nicer way of getting yourself wired with a `BeanFactory` or `ApplicationContext`, e.g.

```
private @Autowired ApplicationContext appContext;
private @Autowired BeanFactory beanFactory;
```

No need for the `XyzAware` interfaces.

Comment: In autowired case is it possible to catch appContext/beanFactory set event? In constructor appContext/beanFactory has not set yet...

Answer (score 4):

An `ApplicationContext` is an extended version of a `BeanFactory` and therefore offers additional functionalities.

So whether to use `ApplicationContextAware` or `BeanFactoryAware` boils down to the question: Do you explicitely need any of the additional `ApplicationContext` functionalities? If you do implement `ApplicationContextAware` otherwise stick to `BeanFactoryAware`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you require access to the additional features available on an ApplicationContext? If so, then you should of course use **ApplicationContextAware**. If not, **BeanFactoryAware** will be sufficient.

Amongst many other things, an ApplicationContext has additional methods for inspecting the beans e.g.
**containsBeanDefinition**, **getBeanDefinitionCount**, **getBeanDefinitionNames**, **getBeanNamesForType**, **getBeansOfType** that may be useful to you and which are not available on **BeanFactory**

I usually implement ApplicationContextAware